# What's a good unit test framework for Common Lisp projects?

Tags: unit-testing, common-lisp

I need to write a unit test suite for a project I am developing in my spare time. Being a CL newbie I was overwhelmed by the amount of choices for a CL implementation, I spent quite some time to choose one. Now I am facing exactly the same thing with unit test frameworks.

A quick glance at http://www.cliki.net/test%20framework shows 20 unit test frameworks! Choice is good but for a novice like me this can be a bit confusing and given the number of frameworks it would be painful to try them all.

I would like to use a framework which:

- Is reasonably well maintained
- Easy to use but with some degree of flexibility
- Offers some sort of integration with Emacs (or it is possible to easily integrate it with Emacs)
- It is possible to integrate it with git post-commit hooks
- It is possible to integrate it with a continous integration system (such as buildbot)

What are your experiences in this field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you see the link to http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/notes-on-lisp-testing-frameworks.html off the [Test framework](https://www.cliki.net/Test%20Framework) link on that cliki page you mention? Phil gives his impressions, and what it looks like to use the various test frameworks.

Comment: Yes but the page "Test framework comparison" is a bit vague and it seems they've been using them only for toy projects. On the other hand Phil's article is well explained and comprehensive but by posting this on StackOverflow I hoped to get many opinions from developers working on different projects of different sizes.

Comment: Indeed! I hope to see those reports myself.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer lisp-unit. It's simple to use and has most of the common types of tests.

http://www.cliki.net/lisp-unit

http://repo.or.cz/w/lisp-unit.git/blob_plain/master:/documentation/lisp-unit.html

I don't think it has any integration with post-commit hooks or buildbot built in.